# Почему браузеры не доверяют самоподписанным SLL-сертификатам даже в случае localhost?

Tags: ssl, https, localhost

Суть неавторитетных HTTPS-сертификатов в случае опубликованных в интернете сайтов более-менее ясна. Но почему браузеры поднимают тревогу на localhost-е?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то странно видеть подобные сообщения для сайтов/приложений, которые доступны по localhost-у.
Что, кто-то другой может использовать мой localhost для публикации своих мошеннических сайтов?
Если нет, то должна быть какая-то причина, по которой разработчики браузеров не доставили localhost в белый список.

Comment: Доверять `localhost` - странная идея. Кому именно браузер должен доверять? Принцип серверных сертификатов заключается в том, что привязывается доменное имя к контролируемому набору серверов. `localhost` не имеет такой привязки: на каждой сетевой машине свой сервер на этом адресе. Браузер понятия не имеет, кто именно скрывается за `localhost` на каждом компьютере. Поэтому и не доверяет.

Comment: @PakUula. Благодарю Вас за комментарий!. В целом я Вас понял, но всё-таки проведу конкурс - всё-таки тема актуальная и уверен, многим будет интересна вне зависимости он языка программирования.

Comment: Ну, можно переопределить в hosts - и localhost будет вести уже на какой-то другой домен в интернете. И это может сделать вредоносное ПО. Суть сертификатов в том, чтобы такой трюк не прошёл: например открыли вы gmail, а там предупреждение о сертификате - это значит 100% кто-то подменил домен, чтобы стащить ваш пароль.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр ну если вредоносное ПО может писать в hosts, то ему не составит труда и добавить левый сертификат в хранилище доверенных

Comment: @andreymal труда составит, в том то и дело - подменить домен в hosts, это просто. А подменять центры сертификации, или механику работы https в браузере, или сам браузер - это уже сложно, и оставит много следов для средств защиты(попробуйте добавить доверенный сертификат для vk например, и запись в хостс для vk - будут предупреждения от безопасности). То есть усложняется работа над взломом многократно, усложняется распространение вируса.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр для подмены hosts нужны права администратора. Если вирус получил права администратора - он может делать вообще что угодно, в том числе подмену центров сертификации, хотя это будет уже меньшая из проблем

Comment: @andreymal не совсем, множество программ, легальных(например openserver) и нет(кейгенов например) - требуют права администратора. Но они не всесильны, так как безопасность ОС сейчас уже давно не на уровне windows 95, и всё что угодно делать не смогут - разве что прося на каждый чих разрешения, что вызовет подозрения, конечно.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр достаточно ровно один раз спросить разрешение на права администратора, а дальше вирус может делать что угодно, в том числе менять hosts, менять центры сертификации и отключать системы защиты (там, где ещё не требуются права SYSTEM или безопасный режим)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Браузеры не доверяют самоподписанным SSL-сертификатам, даже если вы пытаетесь использовать их на локальном хосте, потому что это может привести к возможности атаки "человек-в-середине" (man-in-the-middle attack).

Самоподписанный SSL-сертификат может быть создан любым человеком, и браузеры не могут проверить, что он настоящий и действительно принадлежит веб-серверу, к которому вы пытаетесь подключиться. Это может открыть возможность для злоумышленников перехватить ваше соединение, перехватывая трафик и перенаправляя его на свой сервер.

Чтобы предотвратить эту атаку, браузеры доверяют только тем сертификатам, которые были выданы доверенными центрами сертификации CA, как (Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/ru/docs/certificates-for-localhost/). Эти компании проверяют, что доменное имя, для которого вы запрашиваете сертификат, действительно принадлежит вам, и выдаете сертификат, который может быть использован для подключения к вашему веб-серверу.

Если вы работаете на локальном хосте и не хотите покупать действительный SSL-сертификат, вы можете использовать сертификат, который был выдан локальным CA, например OpenSSL. Для этого вам нужно создать самоподписанный сертификат с помощью OpenSSL, а затем добавить его в доверенные сертификаты вашего браузера.

Есть умельцы которые решили данную незадачу путём формирования следующего репозитория: https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert.

И в добавок могу порекомендовать Let's Encrypt, у которого есть удобная утилита `cetrbot` для данных целей. На github  у меня есть подробноу руководство по использованию этой утилиты https://github.com/ekangash/laravel-quick-start/blob/develop/!cheatsheets/certbot.md

Answer (score 1):

Самоподписанные SSL-сертификаты не могут быть проверены на достоверность с помощью третьей стороны, и браузеры должны отказываться от их использования с целью защиты пользователей от попадания в руки злоумышленников. Хотя localhost и используется часто для локальных тестов, большинство таких случаев не могут быть подтверждены третьими сторонами. Если пользователь использует самоподписанный SSL-сертификат для подключения к сайту, то кто-то другой может перехватить соединение, подменить оригинальный домен и предоставить ложные данные пользователю.

Comment: Очень интересно, как этот «кто-то другой» перехватит соединение к локалхосту?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Любой вирус сможет. Выше про это уже написали. Хотя если вирус перепишет hosts защита браузера ничем не поможет. Зато если в системе есть левые сертификаты, то по отсутствию предупреждения это можно понять)