# Безопасно ли отслеживать SSL ключи и сертификаты с помощью систем контроля версий в режимах локальной разработки и продакшена?

Tags: ssl, https, контроль-версий

Как известно, файлы с переменными окружения (обычно имеют расширение `.env` с именем файла или без) часто не отслеживаются системами контроля версий, чтобы предотвратить утечку таких данных, как пароли к базам данных. А что насчёт файлов с ключами SLL и сертификатами?
Прошу Вас отдельно рассмотреть случаи локальной разработки, стэйджинга и продакшена.

### Ход мыслей по данной теме

#### Режим локальной разработки

Если в режиме локальной разработки используется самовыпущенные (например, с помощью **mkcert**) SSL ключ и сертификат , то в целом не вижу причин исключать их из отслеживания системами контроля версий. Вроде там так не содержится никаких чувствительных данных.

Единственная вероятная причина заставить каждого участника команды выпустить сертификат самостоятельно - возможное отсутствие в mkcert команды заставить браузеры верить уже выпущенному сертификату. Если такой команды действительно нет, тогда каждому участнику придётся самостоятельно запустить команду `mkcert`, в результате чего будет не только выпущен ключ и сертификат, но браузеры будут им доверять. Сделать это без mkcert на Windows непросто (у меня на момент задавания вопроса не получалось).

##### Обновление на основе комментариев

Как прокомментировал @andreymal,

> Если вы добавляете самовыпущенный сертификат в доверенные браузера, то
> утечка его закрытого ключа позволит злоумышленнику организовать
> mitm-атаку и потому очень опасна

Надеюсь, это не будет причиной использовать в режиме локальной разработке только протокол HTTP (а не HTTPS).

#### Продакшен

Я точно не уверен, но думаю, что SSL ключ и сертификат для режима продакшен являются секретной информацией, утечки которой допускать не следует. С какой-то вероятностью они могут быть так же доступны для общего просмотра с помощью режима разработчика браузера как CSS или JS файлы, но это опять же предположение.

В отличие от самовыпущенных SSL ключей и сертификатов для режима локальной разработки, которые у каждого члена команды могут быть свои, для режима продакшен будет один ключ и один сертификат на всех (скорее всего, выданные уполномоченными организациями на возмездной основе).
Если так, то их придётся исключить из системы контроля версий и передавать между членами команды другим способом.

##### Обновление на основе комментариев

Был задан вопрос: зачем членам команды знать SSL продакшена, если его по идее должно быть достаточно знать одному-двум админам продакшен-серверов?
Отвечу так: в зависимости от того, как организована автоматизация сборки проекта и его деплой, иногда SLL-ключ и сертификат может быть удобно иметь среди файлов исходного кода.

Первое, что настораживает - это то, SSL-ключ должны знать только админы продакшен-сервера. Не говорю, что это неправильно, но при таком раскладе, когда SSL-ключ и сертификат только у одного-двух членов комманды, могут возникнуть проблемы. Например, админ не вышел на работу, а надо опубликовать хотфикс приложения. Или же файлы, необходимые для работы приложения, разбросаны по членам команды, а не организоываны воедино.

Опять же, не говорю, что все должны делать именно так, но я собираю проект в папку, куда помещается абсолютно всё, что нужно для работы приложения на сервере, в частности с ssl-ключ, сертификат и файл переменных окружения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, после сборки проекта файлы остаётся только отправить на VPS тем или иным способом и перезапустить `docker compose build` на VPS.

Я знаю, что есть всякие продвинутые способы деплоя, в частности CI/CD как на GitHub или всевозможные инструменты AWS. Можно, например, организовать инъекцию перменных среды средствами AWS без использования .env-файлов - наверняка что-то похожее и для SSL есть. Но всё это привязывает разработчиков к конкретному поставщику устуг. Иногда это оправдано, но всё же должен быть какой-то способ грамотно организовать деплой, когда имеется один лишь только VPS изначально с голой Ubuntu.

Comment: 1) Если вы добавляете самовыпущенный сертификат в доверенные браузера, то утечка его закрытого ключа позволит злоумышленнику организовать mitm-атаку и потому очень опасна

Comment: 2) Зачем членам команды знать SSL продакшена? Его по идее должно быть достаточно знать одному-двум админам продакшен-серверов (а в случае с каким-нибудь Let's Encrypt даже админам знать не надо, certbot сам разберётся полностью автоматически)

Comment: Я не размещаю секреты ни в продакшене, ни в деве. В продакшене не размещаю, так как круг допущенных к репозиторию существенно больше тех, кому разрешен доступ к приватным ключам. В деве не размещаю, дабы не размякнуть - сначала прывакаешь в деве хранить тестовые секреты в открытом виде, а потом бац! и те же привычки переносишь на продакшн. Единственное исключение - хорошо известные ключи. Есть конечный набор тестовых ключей, которые используются во всех тестовых серверах. При генерации ключей для продакшена особо проверяется, что ключ не равен известному тестовому.

Comment: @andreymal "1) Если вы добавляете самовыпущенный сертификат ... и потому очень опасна" - а как же тогда организовать локальную разработку с использованием HTTPS? Если браузер не доверяет сертификату, то просматривать разрабатываемый сайт или приложение будет затруднительно. Наверняка, Вы помните [мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1523791/193415) на эту тему.

Comment: @БоковГлеб обратите внимание: "утечка его закрытого ключа". А так, думаю, какие-то сертификаты, разумеется, можно/нужно добавлять к доверенным, только секреты храните надежно.

Comment: «админ не вышел на работу, а надо опубликовать хотфикс приложения» — поэтому админов должно быть хотя бы два. // «файлы, необходимые для работы приложения ... не организоываны воедино» — и такую ситуацию тоже нужно не допускать. // «я собираю проект в папку, куда помещается абсолютно всё, что нужно для работы приложения на сервере» — если вы под этим имеете в виду, что все секреты кладутся прямо в контейнер, то это звучит очень плохо

Comment: Вообще, я считаю, что проект должен быть организован так, чтобы в любой момент можно было залить репозиторий публично на какой-нибудь гитхаб и закинуть контейнеры публично на какой-нибудь docker hub. Даже если это в реальности не планируется делать никогда — наличие чего-то, что мешает просто так взять и опубликовать проект (например, секреты в репозитории), может намекать на косяки в организации проекта

Comment: "отказ от протокола HTTPS - не вариант, и его нужно обеспечить ... в режиме локальной разработки" - а у вас среда разработки считается недоверенной? Или вы хотите тестировать всё в комплексе? Сделайте свой внутренний сертификат разработчика (может даже самоподписанный) и поставьте его разработчикам. Только убедитесь, что разработка отделена барьером от внешнего мира и, желательно, от прода. HTTPS  позволяет избежать перехвата трафика и его изменения, что из этого при разработке нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю каноническим ответом может быть такой:
если к системе контроля версий допущены **только** те люди, которым разрешено смотреть секретные части ключей/сертификаты, и вы можете относительно надежно **гарантировать** (на протяжении всего времени действия ключа), что в систему контроля версий не проникнет неавторизованный и/или злоумышленник, то хранить можно. Разумеется систему аудита нужно сделать, возможно какие-то тесты на проникновение сделать. Так же действует правило: **чем меньше людей знает секрет**, тем он (в общем случае) надежнее хранится.

Я думаю @Pak Uula всё правильно ответил.

Answer (score 2):

Закрытый ключ SSL на продакшене это очень сильно конфиденциальная штука, сохранность которой гарантирует невозможность атаки man in the middle как уже писали в комментариях. Система контроля версий это не то место, где надо подобные такие вещи.

По хорошему контур приложения и контур веб-сервера должны быть разные и разнесены друг от друга. Например приложение лежит у вас в `/var/www` а все что касается ssl в `/etc/ssl` куда вообще нет прямого доступа по http и берет его оттуда nginx, apache или любой другой веб-север. Т.е. всё это дело должно храниться отдельно от проекта приложения (сайта/сервиса).

Управлять такой конфигурацией продвинутыми способами можно, например через docker и [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) или [puppet](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/ssl_certificates.html) либо вручную или ci/cd скриптами силами специально уполномоченного девопса с доступом. А у разработчиков может даже не быть sudo прав на стенды, только запись в папку проекта.

Вы так же можете использовать LetsEncrypt через [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) как на деве, так и на проде (если нет необходимости в более надёжном УЦ, минцифрах и пр.). тогда вам вообще не надо будет думать про ssl.

Но в любом случае шифрование трафика это задача веб-сервера, а не приложений, которые на нём крутятся.

К слову, мы для dev стендов используем сертификаты, выданные локально-развернутым ЦС, корневой сертификат которого добавляется в доверенные доменной политикой на все рабочие ПК. Это избавляет от необходимости чего-то вручную к себе добавлять для упрощения разработки.